# Redirect Form After Validated

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to redirect the form on https://sodacitysolar.com/consultation.html to https://sodacitysolar.com/thanks.html once the form is validated.  I've traced the code and believe the solution lies somewhere below, which is the form.js file:

```
$(function()
{
    function after_form_submitted(data) 
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
        {
            $('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

            jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
            {
                $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
            });
            $('#success_message').hide();
            $('#error_message').show();

            //reverse the response on the button
            $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
            {
                $btn = $(this);
                label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                if(label)
                {
                    $btn.prop('type','submit' ); 
                    $btn.text(label);
                    $btn.prop('orig_label','');
                }
            });

        }//else
    }

    $('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        //show some response on the button
        $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
        {
            $btn = $(this);
            $btn.prop('type','button' ); 
            $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
            $btn.text('Sending ...');
        });


                    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'handler.php',
                data: $form.serialize(),
                success: after_form_submitted,
                dataType: 'json' 
            });        

      });   
});
```

I've tried to replace this code with the code below but it's not working:

```
$('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();



function redirect()
{
    window.location.href="thanks.html";
}
```

Any chance you guys could point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

Here's the code I was trying to use:

```
$(function()
    {
        function after_form_submitted(data) 
        {
            if(data.result == 'success')
            {
                 function redirect()
    {
        window.location.href="thanks.html";
    }
            }
            else
            {
                $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

                jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
                {
                    $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
                });
                $('#success_message').hide();
                $('#error_message').show();

                //reverse the response on the button
                $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
                {
                    $btn = $(this);
                    label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                    if(label)
                    {
                        $btn.prop('type','submit' ); 
                        $btn.text(label);
                        $btn.prop('orig_label','');
                    }
                });

            }//else
        }

        $('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
          {
            e.preventDefault();

            $form = $(this);
            //show some response on the button
            $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
            {
                $btn = $(this);
                $btn.prop('type','button' ); 
                $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
                $btn.text('Sending ...');
            });


                        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'handler.php',
                    data: $form.serialize(),
                    success: after_form_submitted,
                    dataType: 'json' 
                });        

          });   
    });
```

Comment: Where do you actually call the redirect function?

Comment: Pseudo code `if(myValudation() === true) redirect();`

Comment: @Bibberty just added the code I tried to use and where I called the redirect function.

Comment: ok, you have wrapped the redirect in a function inside success. This prevents it being called. get rid of the `function` declaration and just leave `window.location.href="thanks.html";` This should solve the problem (if it is successful. Have you looked in chrome debug?)

Comment: @samuel has corrected this for you below.

Comment: @Bibberty Awesome! Just added it without the function and it works!

Answer (score 0):

You created a function block, that will do nothing unless you actually call that specific function.

For example:

```
function foo() {
  console.log('bar');
}
```

Here, I have a simple function which would print `bar` in my Console. However, this function above will do nothing unless I first call it:

```
foo() // bar
```

After calling it in my code I will then see `bar` in my console.

---

You can brush up your [function knowledge here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> Generally speaking, a function is a "subprogram" that can be called by code external (or internal in the case of recursion) to the function. Like the program itself, a function is composed of a sequence of statements called the function body. Values can be passed to a function, and the function will return a value.

---

### Solution

But to make your code work, simply add:

```
//...
redirect(); // calls the redirect function
// ...
```

### Completed code

This is what this should look like:

```js
$(function () {
  function after_form_submitted(data) {
    if (data.result == 'success') {
      $('form#reused_form').hide();
      $('#success_message').show();
      $('#error_message').hide();

      // call the function
      redirect();

    } else {
      $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

      jQuery.each(data.errors, function (key, val) {
        $('#error_message ul').append('<li>' + key + ':' + val + '</li>');
      });
      $('#success_message').hide();
      $('#error_message').show();

      //reverse the response on the button
      $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function () {
        $btn = $(this);
        label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
        if (label) {
          $btn.prop('type', 'submit');
          $btn.text(label);
          $btn.prop('orig_label', '');
        }
      });

    } //else
  }

  $('#reused_form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $form = $(this);
    //show some response on the button
    $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function () {
      $btn = $(this);
      $btn.prop('type', 'button');
      $btn.prop('orig_label', $btn.text());
      $btn.text('Sending ...');
    });


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'handler.php',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: after_form_submitted,
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  });
  
});

function redirect() {

  window.location.href = 'thanks.html';

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the informatoin Samuel!

But when I try to run your code the page just refreshes.  It doesn't go to the thanks page.

Comment: @BillyW I am not sure why that would happen... Not really supposed to do that. I have included the rest of the code within the `$(function() {/*...*/});` see if that works.